# How to set GPU fan lower than 40% RPM?

Tags: bios, gpu, fan

So I have Geforce 730 from Asus and its fan makes incredibly loud noise even in silent mode.

All the software (gpu tweak, msi afterberner and nvidia tools) lets me choose between 40% and 100% of fans RPM.

But I want to set at least 30%.

How can I do it? Maybe in BIOS somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: 'silent mode' only works when the puter is not doing much, not when it's busy. When was the last time it was stripped & cleaned?

Comment: It's new. I just removed the fan and placed it back. It's smooth and clean.

Comment: new? That's a 3-year-old card

Comment: Yeah, and it's still in stock! https://www.amazon.com/ASUS-GeForce-Graphics-Cards-GT730-2GD3/dp/B01EYU5MDG/

Quit posting useless comments, please.

Comment: I'll have to check but I don't think you can drop below 40% because that's a minimum for keeping the card cool. However, are you certain that the GPU isn't in use when loud? You might have unsuspected applications using your GPU.